# Is my simple quiz database with topics & subtopics properly designed?

Tags: database-design

I'm making a simple quiz database, where a question has an answer and one or more image files, and belongs to a subtopic which in turn belongs to a topic. Also each group may belong to one of three levels.

I expect to show a question (and an image, if one exists), and compare the user's answer to the correct answer. I need topics and subtopics to in order to display proper questions.

```
QUESTION
-------------------
question_id      pk
question    varchar
answer      varchar
subtopic_id foreign_key

MEDIA
-------------------
media_id         pk
file_name   varchar
question_id foreign_key

SUBTOPIC
-------------------
subtopic_id      pk
subtopic    varchar
topic_id    foreign_key

TOPIC
-------------------
topic_id         pk
topic       varchar
level       choices(1,2,3)
```

Is my database properly designed? If not, how can I make it better?

[image: diagram]

Notes:

1. Levels can have both unique (Topics 1 and 3) and
   shared (Topic 2) topics.
2. A topic can have one or more
   subtopics, but a subtopic cannot
   belong to more than one topic.
3. A subtopic can have one or more
   questions, but a question belongs
   to only one subtopic. Two questions (Questions 2 and 3) may have the same subtopic and topic, but their levels may differ. Topics (Topic 2) and subtopics (Subtopics 2 and 3) may belong to many levels (Levels 1 and 2). Some subtopics hold exclusively questions of level 1 and others hold questions (Question 4) of level 2 (Subtopic 3).
4. A question can have only one answer
   and that answer cannot belong to
   another question.
5. An answer (or its question) can
   have one optional image file, and
   that image file can be used in other
   questions.

Comment: 'better' requires a notion of how you expect to use it....

Comment: @Mitch: I don't agree. To the extent possible, database schemas ought to be designed without reference to any intended usage. This is a fundamental principle of the relational model. Modern databases suck because they diverged radically from the original ideas of the RM, and as a result we are often forced to consider intended usage. But this should be seen as nothing more than a concession to our dystopian reality, not a design goal to be upheld as best-practice.

Comment: You need to tell us the indexes as well.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos : a good design is one thing, BUT fit for purpose requires knowledge of use. For instance, a highly normalised schema (usually a good thing) might not be appropriate in a reporting scenario where many joins are performed often. Also, 'better' requires something to compare against and this requires that you know how it is to be used.

Comment: @RibaldEddie: I thought primary keys are already indexed.

Comment: @Mitch: Let me rephrase. I don't actually disagree with your advice. Yes, in the real world, you have to consider intended usage. This is not, however, because good database design intrinsically does so, but because our broken database industry forces us to do so. The relational model provides for complete separation between the logical and physical viewpoints, so that a highly normalised logical schema might be stored as a fat but fast de-normalised mess that users never actually see (kind of like how compilers unroll our beautiful small loops into gargantuan code blocks for performance).

Comment: @Mitch: Also, I definitely disagree that "better" requires a notion of intended usage. Many designs can be made "better" in an absolute sense.

Comment: Have to agree with Marcelo.  The whole idea of a database as opposed to a filing-system-for-an-app, is that it is independent of the app, and any app (existing or future) can use it.  Data is owned by the corp, and permanent; apps come and go with functional needs (not to mention quailty).  Replacing apps is cheap; replacing databases is not.  And there is no problem storing the normalised logical as a thin and very fast normalised structure (many people simply do not normalise; or misrepresent their mess as "denormalised for performance").

Comment: @baha  what makes a row unique?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Great question, and that you ask it before building the app speaks volumes for your ability to learn and improve your data modelling skills.

**Limitations of Your Model**

This is normalised in the simple sense: you've already decided what the entities are; what relations you need; you've even decided that they are meaningless things that have no identifying characteristics and you've given them IDENTITY columns as physical keys.  *Then* you've normalised the tables.

That has nothing to do with the Relational Model or Normalisation.

It is typical of thinking in terms of the app (understandable, because that's all you have, and you know the functional needs).  But that has nothing to do with the data.  if you create it from that perspective, you will not get a database, you will get a storage location for the app.  Now if the app was to be written for one quiz and thrown away, that would be acceptable.  But if the quiz is going to be run for a month or two; if the company is still going to exist in ten years; if the quizzes are going to grow; if the stats that are going to be run, are going to grow, improve and mature ... well you will have quite a few problems. Every times you enhance the app, you will have to replace its "database".  At some point they will decide that the app (and the "database" contained within it) is too expensive to change, and ditch both of them.

Even for the short duration that the app exists, because the collection of data is not normalised, it is very limited, the "power" of the RM, that which is implemented in every commercial RDBMS, is lost to you.  Navigation (which is cumbersome anyway, due to SQL joins being cumbersome) is even more cumbersome.  Eg. to get from a child to a grandparent, you are forced to get the parent, even though to are not getting any columns from it.  User can only access the data via the app, it is "closed".  These days there are thousands of report tools that connect to the database and allow the users to perform all kinds of queries, which have not been identified to you yet, without having to wait for a change request to be implemented by the app team: that capability is lost.  And you will have to "re-factor" the data heap every year or so.

**Nomalisation**

Nomalisation produces Open databases, that allow such access without limitation.

Data lives much longer than the app.  It survives the app, and has a value to the org.  When the app gets replaced, they will extract the data and want the replacement app to be ready with the data loaded.  If they did not use a data modeller, new app designer did not learn any lessons from the old app designers mistakes, and the whole repeats itself.

Ok, so the org expects to exist next year.  Ok, so you are going to run more than one quiz in production.  Ok, so you've hired a data modeller to run his eye past your collection of data, so that you don't make those mistakes.  Excellent.  Thankyou.  I accept.

**Relational Modelling 203**

Data is modelled (a) completely independent of the app and any functions that you might know about and (b) using completely different techniques, that app developers do not know about.  So let's get started. This is not a formal lesson re Normalisation (that will take too long, and the theory will bore you to death); this is just looking over the modellers shoulder while he works.  All you need to do is answer questions [every time I post a question mark, please, stop and answer, before moving on], honestly (not suggesting you are dishonest; just reinforcing that "I don't know" is quite acceptable because it identifies an area we have to work on; whereas the clear affirmative and negative allows us to avoid discussion).  Also, forgive me, but I will assume the answers, just to avoid the otherwise back-and-forth delays; please point out any of my mistakes, and I will correct the model.

Ok, you have some Entities that you are clear about, so let's start with them, I think they look like this [**Scribble in the Sand**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Quiz%20ERD%201.pdf).  I am purposely not using standard symbols because I do not want those meanings drawn into it at this stage, because we have not achieved those meanings, and we don't want to convey false expectations to people (including ourselves) who understand standard symbols.

1. How are the rows in each Entity identified uniquely from every other row ? (This is important because it helps us verify that the Entity is in fact an Entity, and not Donald Duck, something not real.) From the columns provided, you would have (at least):
   Question.Question
   .
   Media ? how exactly, am I going to ensure that there are not 42 images which are identical ?  If I allow that, *you* will kick *my* rear end when our boss screams at you, and then *he* will kick it as well.  IDENTITY won't help me, it will happily let me insert duplicates.  FileName is a good identifier. Media.FileName
   .
   Topic ? would you like 101 identical Topics ? I thought not.
   Topic.Topic
   .
   Subtopic.Subtopic ?  No.  IDENTITY ?  No.  You are pretty clear it belongs under Topic, and I am already carrying Topic as a Foreignkey, which has meaning; if it is a dependent child, not an independent orphan, then the FK is an **Identifying Relation**:
   Subtopic: (Topic, Subtopic).
   .
   Ok, we have fuselage.
2. How are the Entities related to each other ?
   You are clear that Subtopic is a child of Topic, fine.
   .
   Question is a child of Subtopic?  I think not.  Do you really want the same Question "how many cars does the household own" which may exist in 42 quizzes, inserted in 42 rows ?  "there will never be the same question in two quizzes" is suspicious, so please don't say it, unless you are going to put it in writing.  What's worse is, let's say the question is a very picturesque one, then we will have 42 Media entries as well.  If the boss gets upset at having to change the same question in 42 places, and when he does that he finds some of the images were ancient, they were not updated when the major image update took place last year ... it's your rear end.
   .
   How about we allow for the possibility of a Question existing in more than one Quiz ?
   .
   So Question is Independent.
3. Back to Entities.  In our discussions, starting with the fifth word, you keep saying "Quiz", and I keep saying it, but we don't have an Entity for it.  I can't imagine a loose and duplicated set of Questions, that I've just de-duplicated, without identifying said collection of Questions.  Now you may say "actually the Quiz is the Topic", but that is very restrictive: every time the boss needs to add a quiz for some new customer, he has to add the whole Topic/Subtopic/Question *set* all over again, even when he knows he has entered those exact Questions before, in existing Quizzes; which is why he won the new business, and why he was going to finally make a profit, which you've just reduced to zero.  My rear end is still hurting from his last upset, so let's make sure he does not have another excuse.  This let's him grow, nurture, and change Quizzes and Topic/Subtopics independently, without duplication of Questions:
   .
   Entity.  Quiz
   Key ?  Well, it better have an index on it to ensure we do not supply him with duplicate Quizzes.  Let's say that we don't want to carry CHAR(80) keys into the children, and the user think a ShortName CHAR(12) that they get to make up is a nice identifier, better than a 10 digit number.
   Quiz: QuizCode
   .
   ok, we have fuselage big enough for payload.  So far we have this [**Improved Scribble in the Sand**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Quiz%20ERD%202.pdf).
4. What Entities are truly Independent, that can exist without the existence of other Entities; and the remainder, which exists only in the context of another Entity ?
   Media is still a bit up in the air.  While we have excluded duplicate FileNames, we have not allowed for the same Image being used in more than one Question.  Let's allow that.  We do not want an IDENTITY, we are already carrying the Question PK, so it is (a) Dependent and (b) Identified, by the parent.
   .
   Question PK as CHAR(255) was fine before, but carrying it as the FK in the child becomes silly.  You like IDENTITY, and there are going to be millions of Questions.  Fine.
   Question.QuestionId
   .
   Let's give these **Independent Entities** square corners, and leave the children **Dependent Entities** round.  Now we have this [**almost, but not quite, Entity Relation Diagram**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Quiz%20ERD%203.pdf).
5. Let's finish the Relations.  So far we have:
   A Quiz can have many Questions, and a Question can exist in many Quizzes.
   Question is a child of Subtopic, but it is Independent.
   Media exists only in the context of Question, as an option.
   .
   Since we live in an Universe that has some order, and our endeavour is a scientific one, let's give a child of it some order. I think we now qualify for a [**Logical Entity-Relation Diagram**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Quiz%20ERD.pdf).
   The solid lines are **Identifying Relations**; the broken lines aren't.  Now, because we have applied some standard requirements to the Entities and Relations, we can use standard symbols.  Feel free to point out my mistakes.

That's it, we are done.  I hope I have conveyed that the exercise is back-and-forth, that's why it is called modelling.  The astronauts have separate, private quarters, and they can communicate with each other.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

What's that ?  You want the **Data Model** as well ?  Ok, give me five minutes.  Please grab a coffee for yourself.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

It is small enough that I may as well give you the physical [**Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Quiz%20DM%20101031.pdf).  I use the  [**IDEF1X**](http://www.idef.com/IDEF1x.htm) methodology for modelling Relational Databases, which is a standard, the Data Model is therefore rendered in [**IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf), please check that link if you need a quick review of what the symbols mean.
.

6. Many-to-many Relations are a logical concept, and drawn as such in the Logical Model. They are implemented as **Associative** tables in the physical model. I have supplied that.  A Normalised database has more tables (nothing to be afraid of) but fewer columns per table, and no duplicate columns (no Update Anomalies).
7. Oh my God. The Topic and SubTopic columns are huge!  We can't migrate those fat foreign keys into Question.  [Discuss with The Business Users.]  Ok, they say there will be only one hundred Topics and a few thousand Subtopics.  No need for a NUMERIC(10,0).  They want the full Topic and Subtopic in the drop-downs, and they agree it has to be unique, but an additional short CHAR(6) code would be nice.

See, it does go back-and-forth. Paper is cheap; discuss with anyone and everyone; improve, correct, change, modulate, ameliorate, without creating a single table or writing a line of code; at the you will have a model worth writing code for.  Anything else is *not*.  The only way to learn is by presenting something solid, and having it knocked back or changed; make all your mistakes on paper, not in the database.

Note that a **Surrogate** key is *always* an *additional* key, an *additional* index.  They are **never** a substitute for the Key (which is what you had, and what Eddie was trying to get you to think about: you were not preventing duplicates, you merely had a meaningless key guaranteeing the rows were unique, like a spreadsheet; and a false sense of security).  So we need to minimise them, not stamp them willy nilly on every table.

I hope I have shown above, simplistic rules such as "never use surrogates" and "always use surrogates" are too stupid to discuss.  No, careful modelling means: understand and consider that they are *additional*, not in substitute of, the real Key.  Use only when you have to, and when you have to, use them.  Here I have managed to get away with just one IDENTITY.  And the three short codes that are meaningful to the users are surrogates, but they have meaning; IDENTITY columns don't (they *end up* having meaning, which they can't support, which is part of the problem out there).

I will leave the DataTypes to you.  But please keep in mind, varchars and Nullable columns force the column to be variable.  Really slow if used in an Index (every entry has to have a bit of "unpacking" on every access, even the intermediate levels), so that must be avoided, unless you want to supply the boss with a slow database.

Likewise if you don't want the overhead of your rows on the page being moved on every UPDATE, fixed length columns all around.  Which means we can't be lazy and varchar everything.

Ok, now we have a chamber to contain rocket fuel.

**Response to Comments 1**

*from your last data model, would it be better if I omitted topicCode from the question table? DOesn't it feel little redundant to include topicCode in both the subtopic and question tables?*

Excellent question.

(The last, fifth, is the Data Model; the fourth is the Entity Relation Diagram; the first three are pie in the sky, getting there.)

1. A Primary Key migrated as a Foreign Key in the child, is not redundant, it is required.
2. The Subtopic PK is (TopicCode, SubtopicCode), a **Compound Key** (which commercial databases support, as a requirement of the Relational Model).  Above the horizontal line in Subtopic.

   - Some developers are scared of Compound Keys because they require more than one reference in the WHERE clause (pure laziness; SQL is cumbersome with joins; deal with it).
     .
3. That is because the relation Topic::Subtopic is an **Identifying** relation, which means the PK of the Parent is used to construct the PK of the Child, forming a Compound Key.  Note the Parent PK has to be carried in the Child anyway, as a FK, so it is not redundant; it is required.  This is known to substantially increase the "power" or "relationality" of the db, and substantially increase ease of use (power users are often more adept in using a RDb than developers).

   - That is why it is identified as the standard: IDEF1X is a standard that enforces a stricter application of the Relational Model; it promotes thoughtful consideration of all Keys, which of course is crucial to the "relationality" of a supposed Relational Database.
     .
4. In Question, the FK to Subtopic is therefore (TopicCode, SubtopicCode).
5. If you used IDs in Topic and SubTopic, then Question would have (SubtopicId) as the FK to Subtopic, and you lose both navigational power and meaning.

   - One reason that using compound keys which identify the parent (and grandparent) is superior to using IDs is, eg. when you need columns from Question and Topic only, you do not *have* to SELECT from Subtopic, you can get TopicCode directly from Question; whereas with IDs, you are forced to SELECT from Subtopic, which is not part of the report requirement, it is an imposition due to poor relational modelling; failure to implement Identifying Relations, strong meaning.  Just One Reason that data heaps that have IDs only as PKs (carried as FKs) perform much more work than Normalised Relational Databases.

     - Because the tables concerned are simple and small, this may not be a good example for demonstrating the superiority of Relational keys/limitation of IDENTITY columns; consider any large Grandparent::Parent::Child tables.
     - A better example for demonstrating this superiority/limitation, and worth consideration for anyone wishing to discuss this issue further, is the [**Data Model from my Advanced Course**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/Order%20DM%20Advanced.pdf), because this issue is addressed explicitly.
   - Another reason is lost meaning. Eg. an user can simply SELECT TopicCode, SubtopicCode, Question FROM Question, and make sense of result set.

**Response to Comments 2**

[**Progressed Data Model 101102**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Quiz%20DM%20101102.pdf)

**Response to Comments 3**

*I don't understand how you can use the same image file with different questions?*

Simple eg. "name a flightless bird" and "what is an Emu" can both *use* the same photograph of an Emu.  That was my assumption as per (1) in the main post above.  The model allows it by providing a Non-Unique index on FileName.

*Should you include Media.FileName foreign key in the Question table and remove QuestionId from the Media table?*

Well, no.   There are several advantages to the way I have modelled it.  If it is in the Question table, then some large potion of the time, it will be Null.  You need an index on Filename to search on them; see if it is used; or not; etc.  Which means we cannot index the FileName column (or we can index it, but the index will be slow due to Nulls). Right now it is modelled as:

- an "option" or Subtype of Question (one that has an image)
- No Nulls
- Fast Non-unique Index

It can be set up as an image bank (Unique index).  We know a Question can have zero-to-one Images.  You can tell us your decisions, and I will change the model:

- Images are Unique re FileName; they can be used in only one Question
- Images are Unique re FileName; they can be used in more than one Question

*And what kind of relationship is that? 1::1?*

Yes.  With the Media end being "optonal".  Precisely: one Question has zero-or-one Media. Hence "May Have" is the Verb Phrase or Title of the relation.

The model is drawn with The Natural hierarchy in mind: Parents are above children; subtypes are on the same horizontal.

*Doesn't look like other n::n or 1::n relationships.*

There are no n::n relations.  (There was one at the Logical level; which was implemented as the Associative table at the physical level.)

**Why did you include the Answer field in the QuizQuestion table?*

Where would you like to store the users' answers ?

See, you need the Quiz and QuizQuestion tables; they were valid entities before, you did not see that then, but you do now.

*The relationship between topics and subtopics are defined in the Subtopic table. In the Question table, you have included TopicCode and SubtopicCode. You said (if I'm not mistaken) that including the TopicCode is good because I can get to the Topic directly from the Question table without joining the Subtopic table.*

Yes.  As per (1.Subtopic) above.

*But, given your model, every time when I enter a new question to the DB, I should choose a topic and a subtopic [for the question, from the existing list].*

Well, you have to do that anyway; the model just enforces it.  I understood (from the data) that that is what you needed.  One Suptopic can belong to more than one Topic.  So you have to give it both a Topic and a Subtopic (the specific combination).

*How does this database make sure that the subtopic belongs to a certain topic as described in the Subtopic table?*

You don't see that ?  Can you see that the Subtopic table already supplies specific [whatever you have inserted] Topic::Subtopic combinations ... and not others ?  Ok, so when you add a new Question, and give it a Topic and Subtopic (which is the Primary Key of SubTopic, and the Foreign Key in Question), the database will enforce the FK such that only one of the combinations of Topic::Subtopics that exist in SubTopic can be used.

That's a small insight into the power of Good Natural Relational Keys.

That's the beauty of a good Relational model: it supplies many requirements from a single [correctly modelled] structure.

**Response to Comments 4**

[**Progressed Data Model 101103**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Quiz%20DM%20101103.pdf)

[**Progressed Data Model 101109**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Quiz%20DM%20101109.pdf)

[**IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps you've already answered to this question, but I still cannot understand it: Let's say I've the following data in the DB: Topic table has (1, algebra) and (2, geometry) as (TopicCode, Topic). And Subtopic table has  (1, 1, equations) and (2, 2, triangles) as (TopicCode, SubtopicCode, Subtopic). Obviously, when I am inputting new questions, this data will show up as drop downs under Topic and Subtopic. Now what prevents me from inputting (1, 1, 2, 1, Q1, A1) in the Question table as (QuestionId, TopicCode, SubtopicCode, GradeCode, Question, Answer)? continued in the next comment.

Comment: Clearly I'm trying to say that the question belongs to algebra topic and also to triangles subtopic (which belongs to geometry topic).

Comment: 1. The PK of Subtopic is a Compound Key (TopicCode, SubtopicCode) **together, as one unit**, not separate. Since there is no Subtopic (1,2), the Insert will fail. That is the basic operation of a FK::PK constraint. 2. You have less understanding of programming than I previously thought. You must write *your* program, such that the user can *only* choose from the drop-downs. They cannot choose a Subtopic (1,2) because it does not exist ... and *your* pgm will never get to the point where it tries to insert Question (1, 1, 2, 1, Q1, A1) to the database.

Comment: 3. Forget about keys and numbers, users need meaning: in the drop-downs, they will see (Algebra, Equations) not (1,1) or (2,2). 4. Computers do not read minds, then only execute program (incl. database) code. You cannot stop stupid users from inserting an (Algebra, Equations) Question under (Geometry, Triangles). But inserting (Algebra, Triangles) Questions is prevented. 5. The reason I have TopicCode, SubtopicCode, is that you are a human too; Surrogate Keys such as (Alg,Eqn), (Gmt,Trg) are more meaningful than (1,1), (2,2), and especially relevant when you are debugging.

Comment: Re (1) the FK declaration is: ALTER TABLE Question ADD CONSTRAINT Subtopic_Question_fk FOREIGN KEY (TopicCode, SubtopicCode) REFERENCES SubtopicCode (TopicCode, SubtopicCode). There is no FK between Question and Topic.

Comment: You're welcome again.  For a different approach, more top down, by someone who knew their relations were unclear, you might be interested in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082286/).

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, thanks for the link. I've reviewed Progression 101103 (I wonder what that number means, though). As you might have seen from the CFA curriculum, there are some subtopics that only appear in Level 1, and there are others that only appear in Level 2. If I am making a new question that belongs to level 1, wouldn't it be better to show only those subtopics that belong to level 1 in a dropdown list? I think it would be easier to look through a fewer number of subtopics and choose one. Does your model show that subtopic <-> level relationship? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Baha: ISO Standard Date yyYYMMDD (sortable, no ambiguity); no one needs to be told what century this is.  *some subtopics that only appear in Level 1, and there are others that only appear in Level 2*. Sure, AND there are subtopics they appear at both level 1 & 2 (Read your previous comments & CFAI). There *was* a Level::Subtopic relation in 101102 but we detached it & attached it to Question. So no, there is no longer a relation, you cannot show "Subtopics for Level X".  But the person entering Questions is an admin, not a user; they have to *choose* Topic; Subtopic; Level, then insert.

Comment: Users (taking a Quiz) choose a Level; a Topic, then you pgm can show only the Subtopics that do have Questions at that Level.  Then they choose a Subtopic, and it shows only those Questions.  You're welcome Baha !

Answer (score 3):

Since Question belongs to a subtopic, the Question table should have a foreign key to the subtopic id

Answer (score 3):

Sure, this is normalized and looks fine given your requirements. However, you may have left off the `subtopic_id`  on the question table.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should name ids after their tables, e.g., question_id, media_id, etc. (In their primary key locations, that is, not just when they are used as foreign keys.) This makes joins easier, since you can say things like `FROM question JOIN MEDIA USING (question_id)`).
2. The question table is missing a subtopic_id.
3. You may want to replace level with level_id, having a foreign key on a LEVEL table, but that's not a hard-and-fast rule, just a suggestion. It's more flexible, but also more work; it ultimately comes down to what makes sense for your problem domain.

Other than those minor errata, it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to naming conventions:

Primary key: someNameId
Foreign key: someOtherName_Id

At the moment in few tables you have media_id and question_id. It's unclear what's what without looking at the data structure. Now imagine you have 80 tables and 20 to 40 attributes in each table. You'll get lost in where is a foreign key and where is a primary key.

Comment: I disagree strongly.  With one exception, the column name for the PK and the FK should always be **identical**: In the child, ParentKey has strong meaning.  The only exception is where the role changes or where it is ambiguous.  The PartId PK in the Assembly table, which has two PartId FKs, will be AssemblyId and ComponentId.  Separately, if you have 80 tables with 20 to 40 columns in each, which of course means you have FKs all over the place, you have an un-normalised data heap, not a database. Now there, you would need help with all those duplicate FKs, but not in a database.

Comment: Clarity.  media_id is always media i.d., and nothing but.  If it is in media, then it is the PK.  If it is anywhere else, it is an FK.  What is unclear about that ?  I do not need to see the Data Model, but I would, if it has been drawn is some logical manner, that conveys meaning and order, and not 80 tables squeezed into the rectangular frames of pages..

Comment: Give me an example of a header table with 5 or more foreign keys and I'll explain my point.

Comment: @vikp: you made your point, you provide the example, and you explain it.  I have very few such tables, and they are customers, not mine to flaunt.  And they certainly do not have the problem that you allude to.  Second, does that mean that tables with less than 5 FKs do not have your problem ?  If so, that means most peoples' tables.  You are trying to solve a problem that isn't there, that only you have (due to your unnormalised colloection o data).  See, you really need to provide your example.

Comment: Oki, you are writing a left join on a table. Join is likely to be between primary key and foreign key. When you read your join clause it will be Left Join B.CustomerId On C.CustomerId. From reading this, how do you know which one of these tables has a CustomerId as primary key, and which one has CustomerId as a foreign key? Ok, simple example. It's likely that C denotes Customer table, but what if you are unfamiliar with data structure? Left Join C.CustomerID on B.Customer_Id makes it obvious that B is a table with Customer_Id as a foreign key.

Comment: @vikp: I have difficulty accepting your logic.  Have you tried sp_help <table> ? can you not see the FKs vs PKs vs Indices ? How can you write join code if you are "unsure" which is which, "unfamiliar" ?  *Get familiar!* How can "ID" vs "_id" indicate FK vs PK ?  Please, don't answer, I am just identified the strangeness.  Nyway, the advice stands because its logic was based on much higher principles.